# Regular Expression Nested Similar Strings

Tags: regex

i have a string like this :

```
"xxxxxxx File_6547845_Whateverishere_S_Md.Txt yyyyyyyyyyyyy File_14787547_Whateverishere_S.Txt zzzzzzzzzzzzz"
```

and i want to only match the String that start with "file_number_text" and ends with "_s.txt" NOT "_S_md.txt"

```
i tried "file_\d+?_.*?_s(?!_)\.txt"
```

but always match String begins with "File_6547845" contains "yyyyyy" and ends with "_s.Txt"

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/L3A2QN/1

Comment: You want to match whole string or text within the string with your regex?

Comment: only "File_14787547_Whateverishere_S.Txt"

Comment: Can you precise this by editing your question? Let's hope @WiktorStribiżew will see that this is not a duplicate of the question he linked.

Comment: Can the file path contain spaces? Try [`/file_\d+_\S*_s\.txt/i`](https://regex101.com/r/L3A2QN/4).

Comment: Yes Sometimes it contain space

Comment: Maybe [`file_\d+_(?:(?!\.txt).)*_s\.txt`](https://regex101.com/r/L3A2QN/5)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file paths cannot contain spaces, just use a more specific pattern insteaf of `.*?`, say, `\S*`, 0+ non-whitespace chars:

```
/file_\d+_\S*_s\.txt/i
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L3A2QN/4)

If there can be spaces inside the path, it will be very difficult to come up with a safe pattern. Perhaps, matching anything but the `.txt` substring can help:

```
/file_\d+_(?:(?!\.txt).)*_s\.txt/i
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L3A2QN/5), where `(?:(?!\.txt).)*` matches any 0+ chars that do not start the `.txt` substring. So, this pattern will go up to the last `.txt` it can find on the line, and then will backtrack looking for `_s.txt`. If not found, the match will fail, else, the match will be returned.